# refreshreport is not a member of 'microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer'

Tags: reporting-services

I just switched from Crystal Report to Reporting Service and created my very first page with a ReportViewer to show my report (.rdlc), below is my code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        q = Request.QueryString.Get("ID")

        If q Is Nothing Then
            MyUtilities.Show_Message(Me, "Please check the ID")
        Else
            dt = GetFullServerInfoForReportingByID(User.Identity.Name, Convert.ToInt16(q))


            Me.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local

            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("ReportDataSource", dt))
            ReportViewer1.DocumentMapCollapsed = True
            ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
            ReportViewer1.Show()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

My VS2008 reports error on ReportViewer1.RefreshReport() and ReportViewer1.Show()

RefreshReport is not a member of 'microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer'

Show is not a member of 'microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer'

What's the right code I should put here to generated my report? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `RefreshReport` or `Show` with `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer`.

Simply set `ReportPath`, `DataSources` and `Parameters`, if necessary.